Doubt in representation theory derivation of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients
I am trying to understand the meaning of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients from a representation theory perspective, not the usual quantum mechanics perspectives. For more context, I am a mechanical engineer with more background in groups and representations than quantum mechanics.
Here's what I have worked out so far and the problem I am facing. Let a group of coordinate transformations $G$ act on $V$, a Hilbert space of functions, as $g f(\mathbf{r}) := f(R(g)^{-1}\mathbf{r})$, where $R(g)$ is a coordinate transformation matrix. Let $W_p$ be an irreducible representation in $V$ with a basis $\{\phi^p_i\}_{i=1}^{\mathrm{dim}W_p}$ and matrix elements $\{\Gamma^p_{ij}(g)\}$. Similarly, let $W_q$ be an irreducible representation in $V$ with a basis $\{\phi^q_i\}_{i=1}^{\mathrm{dim}W_q}$ and matrix elements $\{\Gamma^q_{ij}(g)\}$.
We can define the tensor product of representations $W_p \otimes W_q$ in the usual way with a basis $\{\phi^p_i \otimes \phi^q_j \}_{i,j}$. We can also define a morphism of representations $F:W_p \otimes W_q \to V$ as $F(\phi^p_i \otimes \phi^q_j)(\mathbf{r}) = \phi^p_i(\mathbf{r}) \phi^q_j(\mathbf{r})$ and extending by linearity. (To verify that $F$ is a morphism, we compute $g(F(\phi^p_i \otimes \phi^q_j)(\mathbf{r}))=\phi^p_i(R(g)^{-1}\mathbf{r})\phi^q_j(R(g)^{-1}\mathbf{r})=\sum_{k,l}\Gamma^p_{ki} \Gamma^q_{lj} \phi^p_k(\mathbf{r}) \phi^q_l(\mathbf{r})$ and $F(g(\phi^p_i \otimes \phi^q_j))(\mathbf{r})=F(\sum_{k,l}\Gamma^p_{ki} \Gamma^q_{lj} \phi^p_k(\mathbf{r}) \otimes \phi^q_l(\mathbf{r}))=\sum_{k,l}\Gamma^p_{ki} \Gamma^q_{lj} \phi^p_k(\mathbf{r}) \phi^q_l(\mathbf{r})$ and note that they are equal.)
We know that $W_p \otimes W_q$ decomposes into irreducible representations as $\oplus_r n_r W_r$. By Schur's lemma, $F$ must map between isotypic components, so $W_p \otimes W_q \simeq \oplus_r n_r W_r$ gets mapped to $\oplus_r n'_r W_r \subseteq V$, where $n_r' \leq n_r$. Let $\{\psi_k^{r,\alpha}(\mathbf{r})| \;r=1,\dots,C; \; k=1,\dots,\dim W_r; \; \alpha=1,\dots,n_r'  \}$ be a basis of $\oplus_r n'_r W_r$, where $C$ is the number of distinct irreducible representations of $G$.
Thus, we can write $$\phi^p_i(\mathbf{r}) \phi^q_j(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{k,r,\alpha}c^{pq;ij}_{kr\alpha}\psi_k^{r,\alpha}(\mathbf{r})$$.
$c^{pq;ij}_{kr\alpha}$ is known as the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient.
Here is the problem: in the textbook that I am following (Group Theory in Solid State
Physics and Photonics by Hergert and Geilhufe), $n_r'=n_r$. Why is this?
For this to be valid, I think we need $F$ to be injective, for which $\phi_i^p(\mathbf{r}) \phi_j^q(\mathbf{r})=0$ iff $\phi_i^p(\mathbf{r})=0$ or $\phi_j^q(\mathbf{r})=0$. Certainly this is not true for general functions. Are we restricting our choice to such a basis? This restriction isn't too limiting in physical applications anyway. Or else, what am I missing?
Edit: After some thinking, I believe that we do not need $F$ to be injective. We merely pick $n_r$ copies of $W_r$ in $V$ that $W_p \otimes W_q$ maps to, even if it is a zero mapping. If $n_r'=n_r$, then there is no confusion. If $n_r' \leq n_r$, it simply means that our Clebsch-Gordan coefficients $c^{pq;ij}_{kr\alpha}$ will work out to be zero for $\alpha>n_r'$ (assuming that the copies of $W_r$ are appropriately arranged).

Maybe it's a notational issue, but I don't understand what your map $F$ is.  Typically if $W_p$ and $W_q$ are submodules of $V$ there is not any canonical map from $W_p \otimes W_q \to V$, so something seems off to me.

$F$ is the map that multiplies two functions from the irreducible representations $W_p$ and $W_q$. Indeed, the definition of the map $F$ relies on $V$ being a Hilbert space of functions where you can multiply two functions. $F$ is a morphism, and I have added the verification in the question.

Usually when you think about this in the context of the Peter-Wyel theorem you get an explicit orthonormal basis for $L^2(G)$. I think that as the answer states below you are restricting to this basis.

I do believe that indeed we do restrict our attention to a very specific basis, like a basis of joint eigenvectors for the center of the Universal Enveloping Algebra of the Lie algebra of the group. (In the $SO(3)$ case the center is generated by a single element, the Casimir element, so it suffices to look at eigenvectors for just this one operator. In higher rank there are more generators, but commuting operators share eigenvectors as you probably know, so you can find common eigenvectors for the entire center of $U(\mathfrak{g})$.)
This is just from memory; you should consult the book if they do indeed give more attention to exactly what function $\phi$ make up the basis.
Purely from your post I can distill some hints that the specification of a specific basis is missing.

There seems to be a bit of superfluous information in your construction. Suppose we just consider the representations $W_p, W_q$, etc as living on abstract vector spaces, without ever bothering to embed these into a function space $V$. And suppose that for each pick a basis $\phi_i^p$. Then already we need (of can talk about) a basis transformation that translates between the basis elements $\phi_i^p \otimes \phi_j^q$ of $W_p \otimes W_q$ and the basis elements $\psi_i^{r, \alpha}$ coming from the decomposition $W_p \otimes W_q = \bigoplus n_r W_r$, where $\psi_i^{r, \alpha}$ is just the basis element $\phi_i^p$, but with some extra index $\alpha$ indicating that it lives in the $\alpha$'s copy of $W_r$. The coefficient of this basis transformation are just your $c_{ir\alpha}^{pq}$ and they deserve the name CG-coeffients just as well.
So the fact that all the $W_i$ can be embedded into some big representation $V$ of a special form whose elements are functions seems completely unnecessary.

Or is it?? Maybe we need it to get a nice definition of the very special basis elements $\phi^p_i$ we are interested in?

Formulated as in 1 it seems very clear that the precise value of the CB-coefficients depends on the chosen basis for each irrep. But still people keep talking about 'the' CB-coefficient

Doesn't that suggest that they have a specific basis in mind?

You say that $\phi_i\phi_j = 0 \Leftrightarrow \phi_i = 0$ or $\phi_j = 0$ does not hold in general (I removed the $\mathbf{r}$'s because for each individual $\mathbf{r}$ it is true of course, but that is a notational nitpick.) However: it is true for 'nice' functions. Any counterexample would exist of two functions that are not identically zero, but whose zero sets together cover all of their (unnamed) domain (the manifold where $\mathbf{r}$ lives, probably some obscure entity like 'spacetime', but let's call it $M$). However, when the functions are nice enough (say: real analytic) then there zero-sets are of lower dimension than $M$ itself and so no finite (or even countable) union of them can cover all of $M$.

Another hint that the definition-makers of the CB-coefficients had some special, or at least real analytic function in mind

Final remark: maybe point 3 might be a red herring and the fact that the $\phi_i^p$ live in a finite dimensional subspace of $V$ isomorphic to $W_p$ can be used, by cleverly exploiting the compactness of the group, to show that they are real analytic anyway and so we don't need to specify them further. If your book consistently refuses to further specify them this might be the real answer and I can think a bit harder about how to make this argument precise again.
Still I do feel that most likely the answer lies in having more detailed information about $V$ and its inhabitants. I.e. in the physics application, do we not always have $G = SO(3)$ and $M = S^2$? Pehaps the general case is then something like $G = SO(n)$ and $M = SO(n)/SO(n-1)$, although likely more general cases exist as well

Thanks for the detailed answer. I now understand that "the" Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are defined in a special basis (spherical harmonics) in the usual quantum mechanics literature. In the general case, as you mention, the explicit value of the coefficients certainly depends on the choice of basis.

Yes, I wanted to type an answer like what you say in the comments, but I could not find a source confirming that that is what going on, so I decided that I could only point out the reasoning why something like that must be true.
